# What is the best solution in Cakephp 3 routing with language prefix?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

what is the top solution in cakephp 3 routing with language prefix ?

like www.exemple.com/en/pages/view/1

Comment: That's like asking "_what's the best sports car_", such questions are rather unsuited for SO. Please rephrase your question to make it a question about a specific technical problem/implementation, rather than an invitation for people to post their opinions.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the built in LocaleFilter](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Routing/Filter/LocaleSelectorFilter.php).

See [the documentation for dispatcher filters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html#dispatcher-filters) if you don't know how to use it.

Comment: thanks, but localefilter is for locale sent from browser no ?
Question: How to setup cakephp router work with locale url

lilke :
$routes->connect('/:language/:controller/*', [], ['language' => 'fr|en|nl']);
    $routes->connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', [], ['language' => 'fr|en|nl']);

Comment: If you are using version 2.x it's ok. But if you are using a 3.x version. Cake's documentation says LocalFilter has been deprecated.